# Hibernate JPA Update data

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a database with 3 entities: User, Profile and UserProfile. When I update the user, I have an error.

```
public class User implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqUser", sequenceName = "seqUser")
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqUser")
  private Integer id;

  private String email;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<UserProfile> userProfiles = new ArrayList<UserProfile>();

}
```

And

```
 public class Profile implements Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Id
      @SequenceGenerator(name="seqProfile", sequenceName ="seqProfile")
      @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seqProfile")
      private Integer id;

      private String codeProfile;

      private String libelleProfile;

      @OneToMany(mappedBy="profile", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
      @JsonIgnore
      private List<UserProfile> userProfiles = new ArrayList<UserProfile>();
    }
```

and

```
 public class UserProfile implements Serializable {
      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      @Id
      @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqUserProfile", sequenceName = "seqUserProfile")
      @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seqUserProfile")
      private Integer id;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "idUser")
      @JsonIgnore
      private User user;

      @ManyToOne
      @JoinColumn(name = "idProfile")
      private Profile profile;
    }
```

My Repository :

```
public interface IUserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{
  User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

My Service :

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService{
    @Autowired
    private IUserRepository userRepository;

    public User getUserByEmail(String email) {

        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public void updateUser(User user) {
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

}
```

My Controller :

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @PutMapping(value="/user/{id}", consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateUser(
            @PathVariable(value="id", required = true) Integer id,
            @RequestBody User user) {           

        userService.updateUser(user);

        return new ResponseEntity<User>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
}
```

Logs & error:

> Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_19_1_, user0_.email as email4_19_1_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
>   Hibernate: select profil0_.id as id1_13_0_, profil0_.code_profil as code_pro2_13_0_, profil0_.libelle_profil as libelle_3_13_0_ from profil profil0_ where profil0_.id=?
>   2018-12-30 00:38:15.385 DEBUG 10692 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select nextval ('hibernate_sequence') Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
>   2018-12-30 00:38:15.389  WARN 10692 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
>   2018-12-30 00:38:15.389 ERROR 10692 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR : Therelation « hibernate_sequence » doesn't existe  Position : 17

My json flux:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "email",
    "userProfiles": [
        {
            "profile": {
                "id": 1,
                "codeProfile": "ADMIN",
                "libelleProfile": "Administrateur",
            }
        },
        {
            "profile": {
                "id": 2,
                "codeProfile": "PROFILE2",
                "libelleProfile": "Profile 2",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It says there is no table named `hibernate_sequence` in your database schema.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What database are you using? And does this database support sequences?

But apart from that the sequenceName attribute is missing in @SequenceGenerator:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_user", sequenceName = "seq_user")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_user")
private Integer id;
```

This sequenceName must be the name of the sequence in the database.

Next you have to make sure to set the back reference to User in the UserProfile class

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements IUserService{
    @Autowired
    private IUserRepository userRepository;

    public User getUserByEmail(String email) {

        return userRepository.findByEmail(email);
    }

    public void updateUser(User user) {
        for (UserProfile profile : user.getUserProfiles()) {
          profile.setUser(user);
        }
        userRepository.save(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: I use postgres SQL. The sequences are seq_user, seq_profile, seq_user_profile

Comment: I updated my answer with the correct sequence name. Have you tried that?

Comment: I have the other error :
org.hibernate.SQL : insert into user_profile (id_profile, id_user, id) values (?, ?, ?)
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 23502
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: a NULL value violates the NOT NULL constraint of the “id_user” column
Detail: The line in failure contains (951, null, 1)

I don’t understand why because I do an update and not an insert. For an insert is it generate while I am not modified this part of the user

I’ve updated my first post from the top

Comment: You have to set the back reference form UserProfile to User because this is not contained in the JSON. The refrence user in UserProfile is responsible to store the foreign key

Comment: What is the solution please

Comment: I have another mistake that tells me I’m duplicating the key. Why it doesn’t detect me that I’m doing an update and not an insert : Detail: The key “(id_user, id_profile)=(1, 1)” already exists.

Comment: Help please. It is urgent

Comment: Can you please post the actual code to see how you save?

Comment: I have not yet done the service for an insert. There I mi what I had for an update

Comment: So if you are doing update you should read the user and then map all the data to this instance an then call save.

Comment: Is it possible to have an example?

Comment: I can’t find any concrete example with rest services that make a crud with join tables

Comment: Help me. It is urgent

Comment: Do you have the source code anywhere accessible? It's hard to explain everything here.

Comment: I don’t have the source code available everywhere. It’s in a private repo because it contains things I don’t want it to be accessible by everyone

Comment: So I try to explain how it should work. You get the user in the controller. Then you have to find the user from the database and update the fields of the user from the database with the data you received in the controller. That's it

Comment: Okay. I’m looking for the user in the database by his id. I put the new information from the received user in the controller in the one I retrieved at the database level. Is that correct? But when I retrieve my user’s information, hibernate only brings me up the id field of the user_profile table

Comment: Are idUser and idProfile the right columns? Should they be id_user and id_profile?

Comment: Yes they are the right columns. By the id of the table UserProfile never returned me

Comment: I found my problem. I forgot the getter/ Setter in my userProfile class, which made the thing crash. However, I still have to keep the setuser as you indicated in your post on December 30 at 10 o'clock because I don’t send the user back to the UserPRofile otherwise I have a circular reference to the json level.

Comment: I think for the update, yes. But I have two quick questions: For an insert how it works: I want to create a user and put his profiles directly into it, but I do not yet know the user’s id. Is this the right practice I use to return my json stream?

Comment: About the insert yes this would work but what you mean by "return my json stream"

Comment: For the json stream, it’s when I select to recover the user’s information, is it okay how I display it because I remove my user from userProfile. See my question above how this is formatted